# How can I use the -PipelineVariable parameter with a cmdlet that processes its input in parallel?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I am querying Active Directory for a list of computers and using `Invoke-Command` to retrieve data from each one.  Because I am calling `Invoke-Command` twice for each computer - once with the `-FilePath` parameter and once with the `-ScriptBlock` parameter - I am using `New-PSSession` to create a single session per computer ahead of time.  As the list of computers to process is potentially very long, I am relying on the fact that, when passing multiple values for the `-ComputerName` parameter to the `New-PSSession` cmdlet, it initiates the connections in parallel.

The output for each computer is a `PSObject` containing the results of the calls to `Invoke-Command` as well as information about the computer; I am using the `-PipelineVariable` common parameter to persist this information from earlier in the pipeline.  What I am finding, however, is that in my final `ForEach-Object` block the `$_` variable (the `PSSession` object) doesn't always match up with the `$computerInfo` variable (the pipeline object storing Active Directory computer information); I am getting the same value for `$computerInfo` multiple iterations in a row with different sessions.  I have inserted some debugging code that illustrates how the value of `$computerInfo` differs before and after the invocation of `New-PSSession`:

```
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile;

Get-ADComputer -Filter $computerFilter -Properties 'Description', 'OperatingSystem' `
    | Where-Object -Property 'DistinguishedName' -Match -Value $DistinguishedNamePattern `
        -PipelineVariable 'computerInfo' `
    | Select-Object -First 10 `
    | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Before New-PSSession: $($computerInfo.Name)";

        return $_;
    } `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' `
    | New-PSSession -SessionOption $sessionOption `
    | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host " After New-PSSession: $($computerInfo.Name)";

        $session = $_;    
        try
        {
            New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
                DistinguishedName   = $computerInfo.DistinguishedName;
                Computer            = $computerInfo.Name;
                OperatingSystem     = $computerInfo.OperatingSystem;
                Description         = $computerInfo.Description;
                InvokeScriptResult1 = Invoke-Command -FilePath    $scriptPath  -Session $session;
                InvokeScriptResult2 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -Session $session;
            };
        }
        finally
        {
            Remove-PSSession -Session $session;
        }
    };
```

Here is some sample console output:

```
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER1
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER2
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER3
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER3
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER3
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER4
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER4
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER5
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER6
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER7
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER8
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER8
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER8
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER9
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER9
Before New-PSSession: COMPUTER10
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER10
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER10
 After New-PSSession: COMPUTER10
```

Note that in the `Before New-PSSession` lines all ten computers appear exactly once, whereas in the `After New-PSSession` lines computers 3, 8, and 10 are duplicated and computers 1, 2, 5, 6, and 7 are missing.  I have also tried passing `-ThrottleLimit 1` to `New-PSSession` and get similar results.

I suspect that this is a synchronization issue.  Since `New-PSSession` is opening sessions with multiple computers at once, whenever it pulls a computer from earlier in the pipeline it overwrites `$computerInfo` with that computer.  Further down the pipeline where I'm doing my processing it sees the same `$computerInfo` variable, so while it's processing a session from earlier in the input sequence `$computerInfo` contains whatever computer `New-PSSession` just started connecting to.  Is this a bug?  Or is `-PipelineVariable` just not compatible with a cmdlet like `New-PSSession`?  Is there a way I can "capture" `$_` and `$computerInfo` immediately after `New-PSSession` so they always stay in sync?  That's how I expected `-PipelineVariable` to work, but it seems there is one instance of `$computerInfo` for the entire pipeline, instead of one per object passed through the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `New-PSSession` might be outputting the object in its EndProcessing override in some cases.  Hard to say if that is happening in this case but to work around the problem replace this:

```
| New-PSSession -SessionOption $sessionOption `
```

with

```
| Foreach {New-PSSession -Name $_ -SessionOption $sessionOption} `
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This is actually similar to the code I'm rewriting.  While I do get correct results when creating each session one-by-one, it is incredibly slow when I have tens or hundreds of computers to query.  I was hoping to use `New-PSSession`'s ability to create multiple sessions in parallel to speed things up.  Using reflection on the `NewPSSessionCommand` class it looks like `ProcessRecord` sets up a list of remote runspaces to connect, and the `HandleRunspaceStateChanged` event handler will wrap them in a `PSSession` and write that to the pipeline upon connecting.